# Get access to all css style properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get access to all CSS properties (not only for a specific selector or element but all) through JavaScript.

I want to iterate through all properties of the `.style` collection.

How can I do this?

Comment: by *all*, you mean all CSS of all elements?

Comment: What do you mean? You have to pick an element before you can access its properties.

Comment: by all means all css properties like style["a"] to style["z"] and style.length = total css properties which we can apply to any element.

Comment: Could you perhaps be a little more specific?  To SET a CSS property to all elements you can use the wildcard character (*).  So: * { border: 1px solid black; } would set a 1px solid black border around all the elements in your document.  If you're talking about getting the computed value of all CSS properties of all elements in the body, then you've got a mighty big Javascript loop on your hands.  I feel if you're needing to do that, you've got a bigger problem on your hands with the design of your webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `CSSStyleDeclaration object`. A CSSStyleDeclaration object makes CSS style attributes available through JavaScript properties. The names of these JavaScript properties correspond closely to the CSS attribute names.

this object has two additional properties:

**cssText**
The textual representation of a set of style attributes and their values. The text is formatted as in a CSS stylesheet, minus the element selector and the curly braces that surround the attributes and values.

**length**
The number of attribute/value pairs contained in this CSSStyleDeclaration. A CSSStyleDeclaration object is also an array-like object whose elements are the names of the CSS style attributes that are declared.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to access style sheets from javascript here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html.

It's different in IE vs. other browsers and it's a bit of a pain to get all the cross browser stuff right.

```
var theRules = new Array();
if (document.styleSheets[1].cssRules)
    theRules = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules
else if (document.styleSheets[1].rules)
    theRules = document.styleSheets[1].rules
```

Often, you can just predefine several CSS rules and then add or remove classes from various objects in order to change the applied styles.

Comment: thank for ans, I think i was not able to explain clearly my requirement, ok let me try once more, how many property are there in css3 , i dont know exact count but i want to access it all from javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
//to loop through the available css properties using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {  
    availableProps = getComputedStyle(document.body);
    $.each(availableProps, function(propCount, cssProp) {
        console.log('CSS Property : ' + cssProp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this truly *access*? Also, the OP asked for iterating over these properties. Could you add these information to your answer?

Comment: ahh thanks I didn't catch that he needed access. Updated my answer.

Comment: The question didn't mention jQuery, a pure javascript example would be easier to understand.