# How can I get computed CSS excluding the browser specifics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get all computed css properties without the browser specifics through javascript/jQuery.
Is there a way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify your question, you want to view the computed css properties for any DOM element using javascript/jquery?  This doesn't address the javascript/jquery requirement but you can use the Inspect option in Chrome to view the computed CSS for any element.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10360960/848164

Comment: Can you be more specific? *All* of the CSS properties, really? Why would you need every single one?

Comment: @Lokase No, I specifically need to get the computed style of some element through javascript without the browser specifics like -moz-...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is a cross-browser example:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

The example is quite old. You probably want to reverse it to use `getComputedStyle` in preference to `currentStyle`.